# Image folder - report of color profiles

Tags: images, color

I am looking for a tool to scan a folder and create a report of color profiles of each image. The report should be a list with 1st column "File Name" and 2nd column should be "Color Profile". We have a hundred thousands images in which some had been scanned and attached with a cmyk color profile which cause some problems when trying to display them in a software we're using.

Comment: Please add some more details to the question. Which operating system are you using, and Which extensions are the file names?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a combination of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and shell commands. I'll use Windows batch since there was no specification of an operating system, but it can be done similarily with bash. I used the .png and .jpg extensions, and you can add to the list depending on your files.

1. Install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and include the directory in the Windows `PATH` variable
2. Create an empty batch file in the images directory, `getColorReport.bat` for example
3. Edit the file and paste the following lines:

   `@echo off
   set "TAB=           "
   echo File Name%TAB%Color Profile > color_report.txt
   for %%f in (*.png,*.jpg) do (
   echo. >> color_report.txt
   <nul set /p =%%f%TAB% >> color_report.txt
   identify -format %%[colorspace] %%f >> color_report.txt
   )
   color_report.txt`
4. Save and run in command line. The result should look somewhat like this:

   `File Name           Color Profile
    
   xx.png           sRGB 
   yy.png           sRGB 
   12345.jpg            CMYK
   etc.jpg          sRGB`
5. If you'd like to filter out the CMYK results, use the following command after the first file is generated:

   `findstr "CMYK" color_report.txt > cmyk_list.txt && cmyk_list.txt`